# Set css to parent node if child td is equal to some text

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I've got for example

```
<tr>
    <td class="attr-sku">Test</td>
    <td class="attr attr-color">10 mm</td>
    <td class="attr attr-yd_length">5</td>
</tr>
```

How could i set a border to the `TR` node that their text from their child `td->class->attr-sku` is 'TEST'

It must be with jQuery or could be done just by javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to find out the `td` which contains a specific text. Then apply css to the parent node.

```
$("td.attr-sku").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "TEST"
}).closest("tr").css(" border-width", "5px");
```

Or you can add a specific class to the parent tr, which will be a much cleaner approach.

```
$("td.attr-sku").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "TEST"
}).closest("tr").addClass("borderClass");
```

Comment: I try both but still don't see nothing.
I was using:
`code`var sku = obj[a].selections[keys[s]].sku;
    jQuery(".attr-sku").each(function() {
        if ( jQuery(this).text().trim() == sku){
     jQuery(this).closest("tr").css("boder", "1px solid red");
        }
    });`code`
What could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery this way:

```
$(".attr-sku").each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "TEST")
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "red");
});
```